# How to manipulate the $x$-Axis of a Cubic-Bézier-Curve?

Tags: linear-algebra, curves, bezier-curve

I have a Cubic Bézier-Curve a la: 
$$
f(x) = A  (1-x)^3 + 3  B  (1-x)^2  x + 3  C  (1-x)  x^2 +D  x^3
$$
with my control constant A,B,C,D which are just constants. 
x ist running from 0 to 1.

What I want is to control the derivative of the graph at the beginning and at the endpoint. I tried to manipulate the $x$-axis while putting $\sqrt(x)$ or $x^{1/3}$ instead of $x$ in the equation. With that I can only decrease the derivative at the beginning but as you can guess, I want to increase the derivative in the beginning phase as well.

In the following image you can get an imagination of what I am thinking about:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWQDb.png)

Thankful for every help I can get. :)

Greets

Comment: You can play around with this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8noorhtuw3

Comment: Are your conditions $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1)=2$? You should plug them in.

Comment: Are ABCD scalars or vectors? Are you interested in the geometric derivative (i.e. the direction of the tangent in the space of ABCD) or the parametric derivative (i.e. with respect to x)?

Comment: @MattiP. f(0) is 1 in this case but you can but it at every value you want to. I don't see the difference if it is 1 or 0 at x=0.

Comment: @PeterTaylor ABCD are scalars. Just a single value. in This case it is A = B = 1 and C = D = 2

Answer (score 1):

The basic intuition you need is:

- $A$ controls the position of the start
- $D$ controls the position of the end
- $B-A$ controls the derivative at the start
- $D-C$ controls the derivative at the end

So rather than trying to find a function $g$ which you can compose with $f$, you probably ought to be trying to find the values of $B$ and $C$ which give the desired gradient.

Comment: Hm, the derivate at the start and at the end is zero. This can't be change. I just want to control the derivate for  0 < x < 1 as you can see in the "Example Images".

Comment: Maybe you should think about a quintic Bézier curve.

Comment: what will that change?

Comment: It gives you more degrees of freedom.

Comment: I will give it a try :) Thank you